# Custom update listener to set subtask's fix-version

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm developing custom listener which will update subtask's fix version to same value as it's parent issue.

Currently we are using post-function in workflow in order to set subtask's fix version according to parent on subtask creation. This however doesn't cover cases when subtask already exists and parent's fix version gets updated. New value from parent task is not propagated to subtask.

I'm using script runner and I'm creating 'Custom lisatener', for my specific project and specified Event: 'Issue Updated'. I added script as following:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.config.SubTaskManager
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.AbstractIssueEventListener
import com.atlassian.jira.event.issue.IssueEvent
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version
import org.apache.log4j.Logger

class CopyFixVersionFromParentToChild extends AbstractIssueEventListener {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CopyFixVersionFromParentToChild.class);
    SubTaskManager subTaskManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(SubTaskManager.class)
    IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueManager.class)

    @Override
    void issueUpdated(IssueEvent event) {
        log.warn("\nIssue updated!!!\n")
        try {
            Issue updatedIssue = event.getIssue()
            if (updatedIssue.issueTypeObject.name == "Parent issue type") {
                Collection<Version> fixVersions = new ArrayList<Version>()
                fixVersions = updatedIssue.getFixVersions()
                Collection<Issue> subTasks = updatedIssue.getSubTaskObjects()
                if (subTaskManager.subTasksEnabled && !subTasks.empty) {
                    subTasks.each {
                        if (it instanceof MutableIssue) {
                            ((MutableIssue) it).setFixVersions(fixVersions)
                            issueManager.updateIssue(event.getUser(), it, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            log.debug "Event: ${event.getEventTypeId()} fired for ${event.issue} and caught by script 'CopyVersionFromParentToChild'"
            log.debug(ex.getMessage())
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, that it doesn't work. I'm not sure whethe rit's problem that my script logic is encapsulated inside class. Do I have to register this in some specific way? Or am I using script runner completely wrong and I'm pasting this script to wrong section? I checked code against JIRA API and it looks like it should work, my IDE doesnt show any warnings/errors.

Also, could anyone give me hints on where to find logging output from custom scripts like this? Whatever message I put into logger, I seem to be unable to find anywhere in JIRA logs (although I'm aware that script might not work for now).

Any response is much appreciated guys, Thanks.

Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figure it out. 
Method I posted, which implements listener as groovy class is used in different way than I expected. These kind of script files were used to be located in to specific path in JIRA installation and ScriptRunner would register them into JIRA as listeners. 
In in order to create 'simple' listener script which reacts to issue updated event, I had to strip it down to this code

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version

IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueManager.class)

Issue updatedIssue = event.getIssue()
Collection<Version> fixVersions = new ArrayList<Version>()
fixVersions = updatedIssue.getFixVersions()
Collection<Issue> subTasks = updatedIssue.getSubTaskObjects()
subTasks.each {
    if (it instanceof MutableIssue) {
        ((MutableIssue) it).setFixVersions(fixVersions)
        issueManager.updateIssue(event.getUser(), it, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false)
    }
}
```

You past this to script runner interface and it works :-). Hope this helps anyone who's learning ScriptRunner. Cheers.

Matthew

Answer (score 0):

Including an "if" will make the script much more efficient.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.event.type.EventDispatchOption
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.project.version.Version
 
IssueManager issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getComponent(IssueManager.class)

Issue updatedIssue = event.getIssue()
Collection<Version> fixVersions = new ArrayList<Version>()
fixVersions = updatedIssue.getFixVersions()
Collection<Issue> subTasks = updatedIssue.getSubTaskObjects()
subTasks.each {
    if (it instanceof MutableIssue) {
        if(!it.getFixVersions().toString().equals(fixVersions.toString())){
            ((MutableIssue) it).setFixVersions(fixVersions)
                issueManager.updateIssue(event.getUser(), it, EventDispatchOption.ISSUE_UPDATED, false)
        }
    }
```

}